# Populating $_SERVER when using popen to run a php script in background

Tags: php, background-process

I'm using the following code to run the php script `email/send-emails.php` in the background:

```
if(strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) == 'WIN') {
   $phpExec = str_replace('/', '\\', dirname(ini_get('extension_dir'))).'\php.exe';
   if(!file_exists($phpExec))
      throw new Exception('Could not find executable: '.$phpExec);
} else {
   $phpExec = exec("which php-cli");
   if($phpExec{0} !== '/')
      $phpExec = exec("which php");
   if($phpExec{0} !== '/')
      throw new Exception('Could not find executable: '.$phpExec);
}

$exec = $phpExec.' email/send-emails.php';
$cmd = strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) == 'WIN' ? 'start /B '.$exec : $exec.' &';
pclose(popen($cmd, 'r'));
```

This works beautifully on both Windows and Linux. The only problem is that `$_SERVER` is populated with completely different values in the calling script and in the email script. For instance, the keys `SERVER_PROTOCOL`, `SERVER_NAME`, and `REQUEST_URI` are missing in the email script. I guess this makes sense, since the calling script is served through Apache, while the the email-script is not(?).

Is there a way to populate the missing values of `$_SERVER` when calling a php script using [`popen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php)?

Comment: Only solution other than what Fire has said is to pass the values of _SERVER you want to send-emails.php via [$argv](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) and set $_SERVER variables your self with those (or just reference the args you passed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to make a HTTP request for the file rather than using popen to run it.

Otherwise in your send-emails.php script you could detect if the `$_SERVER` values were missing and populate them with some sensible defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Consider fallback to environment variables in `email/send-emails.php`:

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?:getenv('REQUEST_URI');
```

so in your master script you can proxy these values to the worker:

```
$exec = "REQUEST_URI={$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']} ".$phpExec.' email/send-emails.php';
```

The syntax is slightly different for Windows.

Please be aware, the solution is oversimplified to show the core principle. In real-life application it is highly recommended to sanitise `$_SERVER` variables before passing to the child process.